# Problema de responsividad (pantalla en negro al abrir apk)

Tags: flutter, apk

Estoy desarrollando una app la cual cuenta con varios carruseles, (este es el que estoy importando: `import 'package:carousel_slider/carousel_slider.dart';`); cada una de mis vistas de la pantallas es un Container que tiene una imagen y texto.

Es importante destacar que hago la emulación en chrome y funciona bien, el error es cuando abro el apk en mi teléfono (se queda en negro la pantalla).

Mi intención es que sin importar el tamaño de la pantalla de mi dispositivo la vista del container del carrusel mida 243 de ancho, (si mide 360 mostrará 1 y 1/3 de otra, si mide 500, etc), esto lo resolví de la siguiente forma:

Antes del return creé estas 2 variables:

```dart
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
double screenWidth = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
double viewportFraction = desiredWidth / screenWidth;
return CarouselSlider.builder(
```

y luego en las opciones del carrusel lo puse de esta forma:

```
options: CarouselOptions(
    aspectRatio: 7.4 / 10,
    height: 327,
    viewportFraction: viewportFraction,
    disableCenter: true,
    initialPage: 0,
    padEnds: false,
    onPageChanged: (index, reason) {
      setState(() {
        currentPage = index;
      });
      widget.onPageChanged.call(index);
    },
  ),
```

Esto hace que al abrir mi app se quede en negro la pantalla de mi teléfono. Generalmente la primera vez que abro la app funciona, pero si cierro todas las apps del teléfono e intento abrir nuevamente se queda pantalla en negro y no abre ni esperando 1 hora. La única forma de que funcione mi apk es quitando este valor `viewportFraction: viewportFraction`, y reemplazándolo por un fijo, por ejemplo `viewportFraction: 0.677`. tengo un error pero es un que se muestra siempre, en la version que sirve y la que no por lo cual no creo que sea relevante, el error es este "Error: Unsupported operation: toImageSync is not supported on the HTML backend. Use drawPicture instead, or toImage. dart-sdk/lib/*internal/js_dev_runtime/private/ddc_runtime/errors.dart 288:49 throw* lib/_engine/engine/picture.dart 90:5 toImageSync packages/vector_graphics/src/render_object_selection.dart 24:20 useHtmlRenderObject packages/vector_graphics/src/vector_graphics.dart 421:40 get _webRenderObject es mas largo pero no cabe... vale la pena acotar que las imagenes estan locales y se ven ..  quizas mas alla de detectar el error lo que me serviria es otra alternativa para hacer mi carrusel responsivo.

Comment: ¿No te arroja alguna excepción en el debug console?